# Creating binary vector showing whether a value is present in a field in R

Tags: r

I have a vector that has 20,000 elements in R. However, as there are so many elements, I cannot be sure if some of them are blank or not.

I want to create a vector of 1s and 0s where a 1 is produced if the element contains a value, and a 0 is produced if the element is blank.

The i'th element of the new vector should correspond to whether or not a value is present in the i'th element of the original vector.

I have a feeling this is easy, but I just cannot get it to work having tried several different options. If someone could help that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you define as "blank" and what type of data does the vector hold?  numeric?  character?  Are you looking for NAs or empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
> x <- c(5,7,NA,NA,3,NA)
> y <- !is.na(x)
> y
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

It rather depends on what you mean by blank

Answer (score 0):

The term "blank" suggested you might be working with "character" vectors.

```
> z <- sample(c("", "something", "something else"), 20, prob=c(.1,.4,.5), replace=TRUE)
> present <- 0+(z == "")
> present  [
 1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

It would be better practice to set those to NA's and the method for doing so would be:

```
> is.na(z) <- (z == "")
> z
 [1] NA               "something else" "something else" "something"     
 [5] "something else" "something"      "something else" "something"     
 [9] "something"      "something else" "something"      NA              
[13] "something"      "something else" "something"      "something"     
[17] "something"      "something"      NA               "something else"
```